# Default Docker entrypoint

Tags: docker, sh

I am creating an image from another image that set a specific entrypoint. However I want my image to have default one. How do I reset the ENTRYPOINT?

I tried the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM some-image
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work like the default entrypoint as it need the command to be quoted.

```
docker run myimage ls -l /    # "-l /" arguments are ignored
file1 file2 file3             # files in current working directory

docker run myimage "ls -l /"  # works correctly
```

How do I use commands without quoting?

Comment: see the help for resetting the entrypoint  `$ docker run --help | grep entrypoint` shows 
`--entrypoint                    Overwrite the default ENTRYPOINT of the image`

Comment: I need to do this in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To disable an existing `ENTRYPOINT`, set an empty array in your docker file

```
ENTRYPOINT []
```

Then your arguments to `docker run` will exec as a [shell form CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) would normally.

The reason your `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]` requires quoted strings is that without the quotes, the arguments to `ls` are being passed to `sh` instead.

Unquoted results in lots of arguments being sent to `sh`

```
"/bin/sh", "-c", "ls", "-l", "/"
```

Quoting allows the complete command (`sh -c`) to be passed on to `sh` as one argument.

```
"/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -l /"
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not because `-c` causes `sh` to only pick up one argument?  I'm using `bash`, not `sh`, and removing `-c` from the ENTRYPOINT lets it pick up later arguments.

Comment: @Mohan I'm not sure what you mean? The `-c` argument is what `sh` and `bash` will run, by design that's a single argument. The quotes make it a single argument, otherwise anything afterwards is ignored

Comment: You helped OP solve his problem but didn't really explained why `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]` is not the same as `ENTRYPOINT []` whereas they are both supposed to be the same as `/bin/sh -c` is the default.

Comment: @DevAb The image default is no entry point, which is what `[]` equates to.  That is not the same as the entry point of `/bin/sh -c` which was set somewhere in an image build by OP (and why I use the term "To disable")

Comment: @Matt I've just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564990/10634206) stating that `/bin/sh -c` is the default entrypoint...
Maybe the default entrypoint acts just like if you would open a terminal under sh as the default shell that is ready to receive a command which is a bit different than running a command with `/bin/sh -c` ?

Comment: @DevAb That's the default way a `CMD` is launched and slightly different to a specified `ENTRYPOINT`.  If you use the shell form of `CMD words` the `words` will be passed to `/bin/sh -c "words"`. The exec form `CMD [ "exec" ]` will not use `sh`.

Comment: Setting `ENTRYPOINT []` lets you go back to relying on that `CMD` logic.

Comment: [Here's where the builder decides to prepend a shell to the command or not](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/33a3680e08d1007e72c3b3f1454f823d8e9948ee/builder/dockerfile/dispatchers.go#L442)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really related to docker. Try running the following:

`/bin/sh -c echo foo`

`/bin/sh -c "echo foo"`

The `-c` means that `/bin/sh` only picks up one argument. So removing the `-c` from the entrypoint you define should fix it. This is more flexible than resetting the entry point; e.g. you can do this to use Software Collections:

`ENTRYPOINT ["scl", "enable", "devtoolset-4", "--", "bash"]`

Answer (score 1):

Note: beware of `ENTRYPOINT []`.

As mentioned in [`moby/moby` issue 3465](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465#issuecomment-684164684) ("Reset properties inherited from parent image"), [Brendon C.](https://github.com/brenc) notes:

> Looks like `ENTRYPOINT []` and `ENTRYPOINT [""]` both invalidate the cache on each build when not using BuildKit.
>
> Simple Dockerfile to demonstrate:

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:4.3-alpine311 as base

ENTRYPOINT []

RUN echo "HERE!"
```

> Steps 2 and 3 will never use cache. This is my workaround:

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:4.3-alpine311 as base

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/env"]

RUN echo "HERE!"
```