# How to commit a docker container with null entrypoint?

Tags: docker, containers

I have an origin docker image, I want to ran a container and modify it, then commit a new image.
I inspect the original docker image, and it has a conf

```
"Config": {
        ...
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/bash",
            "-ic",
            "./run.sh"
        ],

         ...,
        "Entrypoint": null,
        ...
    },
```

I want to keep the same Cmd and Entrypoint for the new committed image.
But no matter I use --change or not, I cannot keep the "Entrypoint": null for the new image. Is there any way to do so?
Moreover, I also use docker-py, it has the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering [issue 23498](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23498) and [PR 23498](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23498), try using:

```
--change '[""]'
# or
--change []
```

> If the array consists of exactly one empty string (`[""]`) then the entry point
>    is reset to system default (i.e., the entry point used by docker when there is no `ENTRYPOINT` instruction in the Dockerfile).

However, if the system default is `/bin/sh -c`... that would not work for you.
See "[Default Docker entrypoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37636548/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

You should write down the specific changes you made in a Dockerfile.  It can be as little as

```
FROM the-base-image
RUN ...
```

`docker build` will preserve the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` from the base image.

If the base image updates, you can re-run `docker build` and get a new derived image; when something breaks in your image six months from now, you'll have a record of what went into it so that you can build it again.  (That is, I'd suggest never using `docker commit` at all.)