# Django don't runserver in docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I have django project and I want to dockerize it.
when I use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` on my system its work:
[view result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xozaJ.png),
but when I try use this command on docker, django server is not running
[view result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVyXH.png)

This is my Dockerfile that used for build docker image:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

I can dockerize project without mysql database(with sqlite) successfully(for test), but i need to connect to this database.

this is my database setting config(in settings.py file):

[image]

can anyone help me to find solution?

Comment: Follow [this](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/) guide.

Comment: I tried this before, and faced with this problem again

Comment: Where is your `docker-compose` code inside it add `command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"` and then build your image run `docker-compose up` it will run your django server

Comment: I know that you what say and before test it, but when run docker-compose up i take same result

Comment: What's the output of the container when it starts up; is it the literal string `view result picture`, or is there some text-format output you can include directly in the question?  How are you starting the container?  Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: I start container with "docker run <image_id>", i think maybe this problem caused by exists some package(like as mysql or python development packeages) in my ubuntu and dosen't exist in docker container, or maybe not / i don't understand first part of your questions please explain it.

Comment: I guess you also need to setup a docker-compose file for binding MySQL

Answer (score 2):

The Dockerfile is not complete. It misses a line like:

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: thanks but This line only shorter "docker run" command, and don't solve my problem

Comment: **Any Docker image must have an ENTRYPOINT or CMD declaration for a container to start.** Though the ENTRYPOINT and CMD instructions may seem similar at first glance, there are fundamental differences in how they build container images. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599659/is-cmd-or-entrypoint-necessary-to-mention-in-dockerfile)